How to Make PageView Items Tappable During Automatic Scrolling in Flutter?
I'm working with a PageView in Flutter that scrolls automatically programmatically. Users should not be able to scroll it manually. The items in the PageView need to be tappable.
The issue is that when the PageView is not scrolling, the item taps work well. However, when the PageView is scrolling, the item taps do not work.

Here are my two dirty solutions:

Remove RawGestureDetector in scrollable.dart. This works, but it requires me to modify a lot of code and may cause other issues that I cannot foresee.
Use GestureDetector to listen to the tap location and then calculate which item was tapped. This solution is terrible.
Is there a better way to handle this problem?

This is original code
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    
    class TapScrollExample extends StatefulWidget {
      static const String routeName = 'TapScrollExample';
    
      const TapScrollExample({super.key});
      @override
      State<TapScrollExample> createState() => _TapScrollExampleState();
    }
    
    class _TapScrollExampleState extends State<TapScrollExample> {
      final PageController _scrollController = PageController();
      int? _tapIndex;
    
      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: const Text('Programmatic Scroll with Tap Events'),
          ),
          body: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    _scrollController.nextPage(
                        duration: const Duration(seconds: 5),
                        curve: Curves.linear);
                  },
                  child: const Text('click start animation')),
              Container(
                color: Colors.amber,
                width: 100,
                height: 100,
                child: PageView.builder(
                    controller: _scrollController,
                    physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      return ListTile(
                        title: Text('Item $index'),
                        onTap: () {
                          setState(() {
                            _tapIndex = index;
                          });
                          print('object $index');
                        },
                      );
                    }),
              ),
              Container(
                color: Colors.blue,
                width: 100,
                height: 100,
                child: Center(child: Text('tap $_tapIndex')),
              )
            ],
          ),
        );
      }
    
      @override
      void dispose() {
        _scrollController.dispose();
        super.dispose();
      }
    }

solution 1 code
a little inelegant
    Container(
            color: Colors.amber,
            width: 100,
            height: 100,
            child: GestureDetector(
              onTapUp: (TapUpDetails details) {
                const double layoutHeight = 100;
                final double tapPercent = details.localPosition.dy / layoutHeight;
                final double? page = _scrollController.page;
                if (page != null) {
                  final double preShowPercent = 1.0 - (page - page.toInt());
                  int? tapPage;
                  if (preShowPercent > tapPercent) {
                    tapPage = page.floor();
                  } else {
                    tapPage = page.ceil();
                  }

                  setState(() {
                    _tapIndex = tapPage;
                  });
                }
              },
              child: PageView.builder(
                  controller: _scrollController,
                  physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    ....
                  }),
            ),
          )


Can you provide example code for more detail ?

@Lightn1ng Sure, I have added it in the original post
